# rxjs: stream of popups

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have to show N number of bootstrap popups one after the other to the user. I currently do have a stream of messages to be shown in each popup. If I do a simple subscription and show the message, it will not wait for user to dismiss a popup and either call `show('modal')` multiple times or alter the message to show only the last one to the user.

One crazy idea is to add a delay per notification using `debounce` operator and hope that user's brain is synchronized with your delay.

I have been thinking about creating a stream of notifications with a callback function for the receiving end to let me know if the notification has been consumed.

```
export class CallbackNotification<T>  {
  parameter : T;
  callbackFunction: () => any;
}

export function notifyAndMoveNext<T>(source: Observable<T>)  : Observable<CallbackNotification<T>>  {
  let notifications = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
  return
 zip(source, notifications)
   .pipe(map(([a, n]) => <CallbackNotification<T>> { 
               parameter = a, 
               callbackFunction = () => notifications.next(0) 
     }));
}
```

then I can simply do

```
notifyAndMoveNext(myMessagesObservable).subscribe(x => { this.currentNotification = x.callbackFunction; showModal(x.parameter); });
```

and at the button event handler of the popup

```
this.currentNotification();
```

The above will not work for sharing subscriptions (publish and refCount), is there anything else that anyone see going wrong that I don't see? Do you guys suggest any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to turn each notification message into an Observable (or Promise) that does not complete until the user dismisses the notification.  Then just use `concatMap`.  concatMap will wait for the previous messge to complete before subscribing to the next

Here's an example:

```
const showNotification = (notification) => {
    // return a "cold" observable using RxJS defer function
    // so that the notification is not shown until
    // we are subscribed
    return defer(() => new Promise(resolve => {
        // when popup calls this.currentNotification() resolve the promise
        this.currentNotification = resolve;
        showModal(notification);
    }));
};

notifications.pipe(concatMap(showNotification)).subscribe();
```